# Indices on Commuting Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose the matrices $A$ and $B$ commute, then

$$(A B)_{i k} = \sum_j A_{i j} B_{j k} = \sum_j B_{i j} A_{j k} .$$

That is, upon commuting the matrices, their indices are interchanged. But, this was easy, because in the above I was multiplying A by B. What if the indices aren't so easy. For example,

$$A_{a b} B_{c d} \stackrel{?}{=} B_{a b} A_{c d} .$$

What are the rules here?

Also, suppose they don't commute. Maybe $AB = BA^\ast$, then

$$A_{a b} B_{c d} \stackrel{?}{=} B_{a b} (A^\ast)_{c d} .$$

Comment: The problem is that in the first expression the notation used is just a shorthand to avoid writing the summation above all indices $j$. To me your expression doesn't mean anything else than just simple element-wise multiplication...

Comment: I added a summation symbol to make things clearer. I have no problems with the first expression. But, I'm not sure about the last two with the $\stackrel{?}{=}$.You can treat those last two as if no summation is occurring, but I wouldn't think it should matter.

Comment: What do you mean by $A_{ab}B_{cd}=B_{ab}A_{cd}$? In the original example of commuting matrices $A,B$ I hope you're not implying that $A_{ij}B_{jk}=B_{ij}A_{jk}$?

Comment: @AlexR. I was not implying that $A_{i j} B_{j k} = B_{i j} A_{j k}$, but I see now that my question of $A_{a b} B_{c d} \stackrel{?}{=} B_{a b} A_{c d}$ does not really make sense. It's not analogous to the original expression of matrix multiplication. Thanks for helping me to realize that.

Comment: $A$ is a matrix. $A_{ij}$ is a number ( or whatever object make up your matrices). So if the objects in the matrices commute then $A_{ij}B_{kl} = B_{kl}A_{ij}$. This is part of the reason for using component notation, it allows the usual arithmetic of the objects. In contrast, $AB$ is shorthand for a rather complicated combination of elements of $A$ and $B$ of which there is not particular reason to expect $BA$ form the same pattern.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Yes, thanks. I realized my mistake in thinking about this.